# How to force tidy not to change HTML?

Tags: html, tidy, htmltidy

I am using following command to format HTML:

```
tidy -xml --merge-divs no --wrap 0 --force-output yes --indent auto --indent-spaces 2 --quiet yes
```

It works fine except it automatically closes tags like this:

```
<br> -> <br></br>
<br><br> -> <br><br></br></br>
<div><input><span></span></div> -> <div><input><span></span></input></div>
```

As you can see it tries to close every tag - how I can fore it not to do that and leave tags untouched or at least close them "inline" like this:

```
<br><br> -> <br/><br/>
```

---

The closest I want is using this command:

```
tidy -asxhtml --hide-endtags yes --doctype omit --merge-divs no --wrap 0 --force-output yes --indent auto --indent-spaces 2 --quiet yes
```

However from this HTML:

```
<div><input type="text"><span>abc</span></div><br><br>
```

It generates this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Mac OS X (vers 31 October 2006 - Apple Inc. build 15.12), see www.w3.org" />

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <input type="text" /><span>abc</span>
  </div><br />
  <br />
</body>
</html>
```

1. I dont want html, meta, body etc tags to be autmatically added
2. I dont want br and input tags to be auto closed
3. why span is in the same line as input?
4. Why br is in the same line as `</div>`?

---

I found option `show-body-only` which does not output html, body, etc tags.
However still output is like this:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" /><span>abc</span>
</div><br />
<br />
```

1. I dont want input/br tags to be auto closed
2. I dont want span to be in the same line as input
3. I dont want br to be on the same line as div close tag

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the wrong flags. Quoting `man tidy`:

> ```
> -xml   specify the input is well formed XML (input-xml: yes)
> ```

but what you probably want is

> ```
> -asxml, -asxhtml
>          convert HTML to well formed XHTML (output-xhtml: yes)
> ```

Comment: Well not exactly because -asxhtml wraps my html in `<html><body></body></html>` which I don't want. On the other side it closes tags correctly ("inline") - but I would like to just skip tags closings...